# How to determine value for single cell within cartesian product

Tags: algorithm, cartesian-product

Say I have some set of arrays with variable size, e.g. `[a, b, c]` and `[1, 2]`

The cartesian product would be:

```
[
[a, 1],
[a, 2],
[b, 1],
[b, 2],
[c, 1],
[c, 2]
]
```

As the number of initial arrays increase the size of the cartesian product quickly gets very large.

Is it possible to figure out what value would be in a given cell `(i, j)`, for any number of initial arrays without having to generate the whole truth table?

(In the truth table above `(0, 0) => a`, `(0, 1) => 1` )

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. (0, 1) => 1

Comment: If I understand your question, the `kth` element of the cartesian product corresponds to the pair `(A[k/2], B[k%2])`, where `2` is the size of the 2nd array.

Comment: That works for two arrays, but is there a general formula for n many arrays?

Comment: Repeat the modula operation with the array sizes from right to left: `k%s4, (k/s4)%s3, (k/s4/s3)%s2, k/s4/s3/s2` for array sizes `s1, s2, s3, s4` with `/` being the division with rounding down. The resulting indices above are also from right to left. I think it could be mathematically proven from Damien's answer together with the associativity of the Cartesian product.

Comment: @Sebastian Note that the cartesian product is not associative ! But your formula seems correct!

Comment: @Damien Associativity depends on whether the result of a Cartesian product of multiple sets are defined as pairs inside pairs (then formally no) or as flat tuples (then yes). Either way the order seems to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13130048/sebastian) and [@Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10553341/damien) for answering the question in the comments.

Here's how I implemented the function in Java:

```java
  public static class CartesianValueFactory {
    private final Object[][] dimensions;

    public CartesianValueFactory(Object[][] dimensions) {
      this.dimensions = dimensions;
    }

    public Object valueAt(long row, int column) {
      long index = row;
      for (int nextColumn = column + 1; nextColumn < dimensions.length; nextColumn++) {
        index = index / dimensions[nextColumn].length;
      }
      if (column == 0) {
        return dimensions[column][(int) index];
      } else {
        return dimensions[column][(int) index % dimensions[column].length];
      }
    }
  }
```